# Snapshot Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting multiple documents, but I do not get the information in real time, what am I doing wrong?

```
export const tiempoReal = async (coleccion, documento) => {
  let response = { statusresponse: false, data: null };
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await db
      .collection(coleccion)
      .doc(documento)
      .onSnapshot(
        (docSnapshot) => {
          const producto = docSnapshot.data();
          producto.id = docSnapshot.id;

          response.data = producto;
          response.statusresponse = true;
          return resolve(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(reject(error));
        }
      );
    return response;
  });
};
```

The data that I get from firebase, I assign it to a state to use the information, inside a useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const platillo = (await tiempoReal("Productos", id)).data;
      setcompra(platillo.ventas);
    })();
  }, []);
```

I get the information, but not in real time, it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a `Promise` and a promise can resolve only once.

If you want to handle the stream of realtime updates, you can either start using observables (look into RxJS/RxFire if you're interested in that), or pass in a more classic callback that gets called each time the data changes.

So something like:

```
tiempoReal = (coleccion, documento, callback) => {
  let response = { statusresponse: false, data: null };
  db
  .collection(coleccion)
  .doc(documento)
  .onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
      const producto = docSnapshot.data();
      producto.id = docSnapshot.id;

      response.data = producto;
      response.statusresponse = true;

      callback(response);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
};
```

And then:

```
  useEffect(() => {    
    tiempoReal("Productos", id, (platillo) => {
      setcompra(platillo.data.ventas);
    });
  }, []);
```

As you can see above, you won't be able to use `await` anymore with this, as that is tied 1:1 to returning a `Promise`, which (as said) can only resolve once.

Comment: why is this warning?: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `yRIVsUeKnpcrpsft96YzOkeVKjD3`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.